# how to select rows data as single column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server:

```
T_Id    Supplimentary_keywords
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Animal, Animals, 1, One, Single,live,living Organism
2       Animals, Animal, Two, 2,live,living Organism
3       Animals, Animal, Three, 3,live,living Organism
4       Animals, Animal, Four, 4,live,living Organism
5       Animals, Animal, 5, Five,live,living Organism
6       Group Of Animals, Small Group, Group, Groups, Small Size Group
7       Group Of Animals, Animals, Animal, Group, Groups, Grouping,live,living Organism
8       Group Of Animals, Animals, Animal, Group, Groups, Grouping,large Group,live 
9       Head, Heads
10      Neck, Necks
```

Now I want to select data from `Supplimentary_keywords` with `distinct` like this:

```
Supplimentary_keywords
----------------------
Animal
Animals
1
One
Single
live
living Organism
Two
2
live
Three
3
.......
```

I am using the following code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Kwd
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         T_Id, 
         CAST('<M>' + Replace(Supplimentary_keywords, ',', '</M><M>')
                    + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data from KWD_Theaurus_tbl) AS A
     CROSS APPLY 
         data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

and getting error

> Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 11, illegal name character

Please help me how to achieve this or correct me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: In order to be able to correct you, you would have to first **show us** your code!

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @marc_s Sorry !! i just want to show you my code that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT distinct Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data
           FROM   (select id,Cast ('<M>'
                                + replace(Replace(suppl, ',', '</M><M>'),'&','&amp;')
                                + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data from #temp) AS A
                  CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

If you have any other spl character replace it accordingly.

Invalid special characters & its substitute in xml

```
& - &amp;
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &#39;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp (id int,suppl varchar(1000))
insert into #temp
select 1 ,      'Animal, Animals, 1, One, Single,live,living Organism'
union all
select 2  ,     'Animals, Animal, Two, 2,live,living Organism'
union all
select 3  ,     'Animals, Animal, Three, 3,live,living Organism'
union all
select 4  ,     'Animals, Animal, Four, 4,live,living Organism'
union all
select 5  ,     'Animals, Animal, 5, Five,live,living Organism'
union all
select 6  ,     'Group Of Animals, Small Group, Group, Groups, Small Size Group'
union all
select 7  ,     'Group Of Animals, Animals, Animal, Group, Groups, Grouping,live,living Organism'
union all
select 8  ,     'Group Of Animals, Animals, Animal, Group, Groups, Grouping,large Group,live'
union all
select 9  ,     'Head, Heads'
union all
select 10  ,    'Neck, Necks'



SELECT distinct Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data
           FROM   (select id,Cast ('<M>'
                                + Replace(suppl, ',', '</M><M>')
                                + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data from #temp) AS A
                  CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: Do you have Special characters in Supplimentary_keywords column data

Comment: Invalid special characters and its substitute in xml
  & - &amp
  < - &lt
  > - &gt
  " - &quot
  ' - &#39

Comment: Yes some keywords are like `Black & White, Black&white, B & W,b&w, B\w, Bw, Black-and-white`

Comment: @pradeep: is your query returning in the same order as inserted,if <garima> needs in the same order we would need to use unions on which am scratching my head on !

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Supplimentary_keywords
     FROM   (SELECT id,
           Cast ('<M>'
                 + Replace(Supplimentary_keywords, ',', '</M><M>')
                 + '</M>' AS XML) AS Supplimentary_keywords
    FROM   #temp) AS A
   CROSS APPLY Supplimentary_keywords.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```